# set -e does not respect logical not

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, ksh

In several shells, the logical not (!) will "invert" the return code of a program.

However, in a shell script with `set -e`, the logical not seems to cause the program to in fact never fail. Why is this?

Tested in `bash`, `zsh`, and `ksh` with the same results.

```sh
$ cat test.sh 
set -ex

# setup
touch myfile

# observe available files
ls .

# succeeds
ls myfile; echo $?

# this succeeds as expected
! ls notafile; echo $?

# why does this not exit when the return code is clearly non-zero?
! ls myfile; echo $?

# this exits as expected when there is a non-zero return code
ls notafile; echo $?

# becasue we exit just above, this never get executed
echo "test passed"
```

Results:

```sh
bash test.sh 
+ touch myfile
+ ls .
myfile  test.sh
+ ls myfile
myfile
+ echo 0
0
+ ls notafile
ls: cannot access 'notafile': No such file or directory
+ echo 0
0
+ ls myfile
myfile
+ echo 1
1
+ ls notafile
ls: cannot access 'notafile': No such file or directory
```

Comment: This is specifically mentioned as an exception in the documentation.

Comment: The [exercises in BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) are well worth reading before deciding to use `set -e`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25) (italics mine):

> The **`-e`** setting shall be ignored when executing the compound list following the **`while`**, **`until`**, **`if`**, or **`elif`** reserved word, *a pipeline beginning with the **`!`** reserved word*, or any command of an AND-OR list other than the last.

Answer (score 4):

This is the specified behavior. From the [Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#index-set)

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a `while` or `until` keyword, part of the test in an `if` statement, part of any command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following the final `&&` or `||`, any command in a pipeline but the last, **or if the command’s return status is being inverted with `!`**.

Comment: This question is about more than just GNU bash. @AndrewHenle has the correct reference.

Comment: The bash reference says essentially the same thing, because it's following the POSIX requirement.

Comment: Still semantically wrong, and it does not do to foster an almost-monopoly in the GNU/Linux world.